# from single column to 3X8 tables

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm

I have a sorted list of names in a single column. I would like to transform the names to 3X8 tables before printing them (printing single column would use too much paper). This is Excel. I'll copy names one by one and paste to a blank sheet.

Using numbers as an example, the resulting order should look like this:

```
1   9   17
2   10  18
3   11  19
4   12  20
5   13  21
6   14  22
7   15  23
8   16  24
25  33  41
26  34  42
27  35  43
........
```

Possible to get a general answer (n x m table)?

Below is what I have got. It's close but not quite right.

```
last_row = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(20000,1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To last_row/24 +1 Step 1 
    For k = 1 To 3 Step 1
        For j = 1 To members_per_column Step 1
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells( i + j + (k - 1) * 8 + (i - 1) * 16 + 1, _
                name_column).Copy
            Worksheets(destination_page).Cells( i + j - 1, (k - 1) +1).PasteSpecial _       
                Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Next j
    Next k
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were already close. I wrapped the code into a function so you can easily re-use it on any matrix size:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TransformIntoBlocks(ByVal MatrixRows As Long, ByVal MatrixColumns As Long, ByVal SourceRange As Range, ByVal OutputStartRange As Range)
    Dim BlockStartRow As Long
    BlockStartRow = 1

    Dim iRowSource As Long
    iRowSource = 1

    Dim AmountOfBlocks As Long
    AmountOfBlocks = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(SourceRange.Rows.Count / (MatrixRows * MatrixColumns), 0)

    Dim iBlock As Long
    For iBlock = 1 To AmountOfBlocks
        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To MatrixColumns
            Dim iRow As Long
            For iRow = BlockStartRow To BlockStartRow + MatrixRows - 1
                OutputStartRange.Offset(iRow - 1, iCol - 1).Value = SourceRange(iRowSource, 1).Value
                iRowSource = iRowSource + 1
            Next iRow
        Next iCol
        BlockStartRow = BlockStartRow + MatrixRows
    Next iBlock
End Sub


Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    TransformIntoBlocks MatrixRows:=8, MatrixColumns:=3, SourceRange:=ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)), OutputStartRange:=Tabelle2.Range("C1")
End Sub
```

Comment: I wonder why you declare iCol and iRow inside For loops instead of outside.

Comment: First of all in VBA it doesn't matter if you declare it inside or outside the loop because VBA will scope it to the procedure anyway. But because of maintainability there are good reasons to put the declaration as close as possible to the first use of the variable. First it improves readability, second it improves maintainability and refactoring in the future (for example if you want to move that loop into a function later it is esier because the variable is already tight to the loop).

Comment: … Third it prevents having a big block of declarations in the beginning of each procedure. If you don't use variables anymore (because you removed some code) you can easily forget to remove the variable declarations (of the removed code) if it is in the very beginning. Fourth, I'm used to declare variable as close as possible to their use because in other languages (eg. In VB.NET) it would scope the varaiable `iCol` and `iRow` to their outer loop. And it is a good practice to have variables only within the scope were you really need them. • So here it's only cosmetic and coding style reasons.

Comment: Would variables be declared multiple times when declaration is inside a loop? That thought keeps me from declaring variables inside a loop.

Comment: @joehua No worries, when the procedure starts the first thing VBA does is to create all variables that have been declared. So the loop has no effect at the `Dim` statement at all. For further investigation I recommend to read [VBA Dim – A Complete Guide: Where Should I Put the Dim Statement](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#Where_Should_I_Put_the_Dim_Statement) and the following section [Using Dim in Loops](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#Using_Dim_in_Loops)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than going through three loops, I ended up just using one loop to write in the correct position using mod.

Seems obvious to me as the writer, but please ask questions if it's unclear- it helps the next reader.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ColumnSplit()

Dim input_rows As Integer
Dim output_columns As Integer
Dim output_rows As Integer

Dim i As Integer

Dim input_sheet As Worksheet
Dim output_sheet As Worksheet
Set input_sheet = Sheet1
Set output_sheet = Sheet2

'output_sheet.Cells.Clear     'optional

output_columns = 3 'Hard coded. Set to whatever you like

input_rows = input_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

output_rows = CInt(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(CDbl(input_rows) / CDbl(output_columns), 1))

For i = 1 To input_rows
output_sheet.Cells( _
    ((i - 1) Mod output_rows) + 1 _
    , (WorksheetFunction.Floor((i - 1) / output_rows, 1) Mod output_columns) + 1 _
) _
= input_sheet.Cells(i, 1)            'cells(calculate output row,calculate output column) = input value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! That's what I'm looking for, a completely different approach. However, it doesn't give 3x8 tables. A 3x8 table has 24 elements. So, the first column should go from 1 to 8 then 25 to 32, like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32 (see example above). As it is now, it goes from 1 to the bottom of the page, say, 40, then the second column starts from 41 to 80, and the third column starts from 81.  I guess it needs another loop?

Comment: Haha yeah, misread the expected results.

Pᴇʜ's result works anyway, just change tabelle to sheet.